# "The existence of a bijection really is an equivalence relation." What is an example that does not express the relation of cardinality?

Tags: real-analysis

There is the following definition in one of the analysis books I am reading

> **Definition:** Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. We say $A$ and $B$ have the same *cardinality* when there exists a bijection $f:A\to B$. We denote
> by $|A|$ the equivalence class of all sets with the same cardinality
> as $A$ and we simply call $|A|$ the cardinality of $A$.

Then, the following comment

> The existence of a bijection really is an equivalence relation. The
> identity, $f(x):=x$, is a bijection showing reflexivity. If $f$ is a
> bijection, then so is $f^{-1}$ showing symmetricity. If $f:A\to B$ and
> $g:B\to C$ are bijections, then $g\circ f$ is a bijection of $A$ and
> $C$ showing transitivity. A set $A$ has the same cardinatly as the
> empty set if and only if $A$ itself is the empty set: if $B$ is
> nonempty, then no function $f:B\to \emptyset$ can exist. In
> particular, there is no bijection of $B$ and $\emptyset$.

Does "The existence of a bijection really is an equivalence relation" apply in general or is this referring just to the notion of cardinality?

If it is more general, what is an example of an equivalence class that expresses something other than cardinality, and what are the associated bijections?

Comment: I think you are misreading. All they are saying is "the relation between sets given by $A\sim B$ iff there is a bijection $A\to B$ is an equivalence relation" which is clearly true.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Are you asking to provide an example of equivalence relation with some properties? Do you want specifically an equivalence relation between sets, or between any kind of object? What do you mean by “THE associated bijections” to an equivalence relation?

Comment: What I am asking is if there are equivalence classes where the sets in an equivalence class don't have the same cardinality. And if that were to occur, what would be the bijections of which the author speaks (since he seems to say that every time there is an equivalence relation there is a bijection).

Comment: Of course such a relation can exist. Take for instance the following equivalence relation: $A\sim B$ if and only if the sets $A$ and $B$ are both finite or both infinite. All finite sets would be equivalent under this relation. In that case, of course there cannot be a bijection between (say) a set with one element and a set with two elements, even though they are equivalent, so the answer to the second question is clearly no. If two sets don’t have the same cardinality, you can never find a bijection between them, by definition of cardinality.

Comment: I agree with the first comment: you are probably misreading the authors. They are not talking about equivalence relations in general, they are talking about one specific equivalence relation: the relation of “having the same cardinality”.

Comment: Consider the set of all possible sets of natural numbers. Can we have a binary relation $\sim$ defined by $A\sim B \iff $ both sets have same smallest element? As far as I can tell this is an equivalence relation. Now, consider the equivalence class $[\{2\}]$. Some sets in this equivalence class are $\{ 2,3 \}$, $\{10^6, 5, 6, 7, 99, 2 \}$, and so on. Where does the concept of a bijection enter this example?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Ok, so the comment by the author was actually specific. I accept that.

Comment: Of course bijections have nothing to do with your example. The authors are not talking about equivalence relations in general. They say that “having the same cardinality” is one equivalence relation between sets

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's helpful to recall the definition of an equivalence relation. Let $\sim\,=\{(A,B)\mid \text{there exists a bijection } A\to B\}$, so $\sim$ is a collection of pairs of sets. Technically $\sim$ is actually a proper class, but the book doesn't seem to mind.

We call $\sim$ an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) if it is transitive, reflexive, and symmetric. We can check that it satisfies these axioms, so it is! As you can see, the existence of a bijection between two sets can be interpreted as an equivalence relation. Therefore the equivalence classes of $\sim$, i.e. the collection sets which have bijections to each other, are called cardinalties.

Side comment: In many fields, we might define an equivalence relation $\cong\,=\{(X,Y)\mid X\text{ is isomorphic to }Y\}$, which literally means $\cong\,=\{(X,Y)\mid \text{there is a bijection }\sigma:X\to Y\text{ which preserves }\textit{(some structure)}\}$. The rules governing these bijections determine the nature of the relation.